# Adding data dynamically to cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an HTML form that I wanna to use to generate dynamically ADD more input fields:

```
            <div class="row cloneDefault">
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <br />
                    <h4 style="text-align:right">1.</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <label class="control-label">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="FirstnameField"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="sname" class="control-label">last name</label>
                    <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="lastnameField"/>
                </div>
                    <i class="remove">remove</i>
            </div>

            <form class="frm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <br />
                        <h4 style="text-align:right">1.</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <label for="fname" class="control-label">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="fname"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="sname" class="control-label">last name</label>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" id="sname"/>
                    </div>

                    <i class="remove">remove</i>
                </div>

                <i class="add"> Add </i>
            </form>

<style> 
.cloneDefault{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

And JS to handle adding input fields dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
      $(".cloneDefault").clone(true).insertBefore(".frm > div:last-child");
      $(".frm > .cloneDefault").removeClass("cloneDefault");
      return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Now, I can easily retrieve text value from an input field by element id and then query cloud firestore:

```
const first_name = document.querySelector('#fname').value;
const last_name = document.querySelector('#sname').value;
firebase.firestore().collection("users").add({
    fame: first_name,
    sname: last_name,
}).then(function () {
     console.log("success");
       })
  .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("error:", error);
        });
```

But how to save **dynamically** generated input fields in JS and save them on cloud firestore? I realised that my code to generate dynamically added input data may be unsuitable if I'd like to use it afterwards. What I wanted to do is similiar as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575572/save-dynamically-generated-input-fields) . Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "dynamicaly". How is that different than what you have now?  Please edit your question to explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Doug thanks for letting me know. I have edited my question!

Comment: I *think* what your looking for is how to use the value of a variable as the **index/field** name?  Not really a Firestore question, but you can use { [fieldnameVariable]: fieldvalueVariable }.  Note the '[ ]' .  This is basic javascript object notation.  (and yes, I use exactly this in many, many places for a JS/React/Firestore application)

Comment: @LeadDreamer Hi, yes I realised this is more likely a JS data structure problem. Currently I used arrays + basic For loop to solve it, but it seems not neat. Would happy to know your solution and I will pick yours to close this post.